# How to calculate average for each column in radgridview into a last row after filtering?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I would like to know how to find average of column based on row filters?

```
private void monthlyGridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<double> everyQuestion = new List<double>();

    for (int i = 5; i < monthlyGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        eachQuestion.Clear();
       for (int j = 0; j < monthlyGridView.Rows.Count - 2; j++)
       {
          //mReport is DataTable which return values
          string value = mReport.Rows[j][i].ToString();
          eachQuestion.Add(double.Parse(value));
       }
          string columnAverage = String.Format("{0:0.00}", eachQuestion.Average());
          monthlyGridView.Rows[monthlyGridView.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[i].Value = columnAverage;


    }
}
```

this code only gives me average not filtered based average?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build in summary row for this functionality. More information is avaialble  [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-rows-summary-rows.html)